# MySQL - How to print a string twice in a cell?

Tags: mysql

I have the "year" column in the photo.

[image: The column]

I want to print the year value twice if it is stated only once. For example, I want to state 1985 as "1985-1985". How can I do it? (MySQL)

I tried the query below. But then result appears as "19851985". I couldn't manage to enter "-" in between.

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`Year`) = 4 THEN REPEAT(`Year`, 2) ELSE `Year`
END AS new_y
FROM xxxx
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why not `CONCAT(Year, "-", Year)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a trivial amount of repeating you can use something like `CONCAT()`, as in:

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`Year`) = 4 THEN CONCAT(`Year`, '-', `Year`)
  ELSE `Year`
  END AS new_y
FROM xxxx
```